# Minimax implement in "Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence" - what are min_to_move/1 and max_to_move/1?

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, minimax

Let me start by saying that this question can possibly be answered by AI wizards with no Prolog experience.

The excellent [Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence](http://books.google.com/books/about/Prolog_programming_for_artificial_intell.html?id=-15su78YRj8C) book has this quite terse and clever minimax implementation:

```
minimax( Pos, BestSucc, Val)  :-
  moves( Pos, PosList), !,               % Legal moves in Pos produce PosList
  best( PosList, BestSucc, Val)
   ;
   staticval( Pos, Val).                 % Pos has no successors: evaluate statically 

best( [ Pos], Pos, Val)  :-
  minimax( Pos, _, Val), !.

best( [Pos1 | PosList], BestPos, BestVal)  :-
  minimax( Pos1, _, Val1),
  best( PosList, Pos2, Val2),
  betterof( Pos1, Val1, Pos2, Val2, BestPos, BestVal).

betterof( Pos0, Val0, Pos1, Val1, Pos0, Val0)  :-        % Pos0 better than Pos1
  min_to_move( Pos0),                                    % MIN to move in Pos0
  Val0 > Val1, !                                         % MAX prefers the greater value
  ;
  max_to_move( Pos0),                                    % MAX to move in Pos0
  Val0 < Val1, !.                                % MIN prefers the lesser value 

betterof( Pos0, Val0, Pos1, Val1, Pos1, Val1).           % Otherwise Pos1 better than Pos0
```

However, the author didn't go to much length in describing it and I'm left to wonder what `min_to_move/1` and `max_to_move/1` are.

Can anyone explain these to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, min_to_move(Pos) is true if and only if the "minimizing" player is to make a move in position Pos. Conversely for max_to_move/1. Personally, I find the coding style depticted here not very good. For example, on several occasions, if-then-else ((->)/2 and (;)/2) seems to be a better fit to express the intention. The predicate names could also be much more descriptive (consider for example "positions_best/2" to describe a relation between a list of positions and a best choice, instead of just "best/3") and more readable (what is for example "betterof" in addition to just being harder to read than for example "better_of"?).